# Finding average of line items from invoices - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, temp-tables

I have this data -

```
[invoicedetails_key] -- specific line item id number 
[invoicekey] -- invoice number
[invoicedetails_itemname] -- line item name
[invoicedetails_itemqty] -- line item qunatity
[invoicedetails_itemprice] -- line item price
FROM [dbo].[vetfeesinvoicedetails]
```

```
invoicedetails_key  invoicekey  invoicedetails_itemname invoicedetails_itemqty
1                   2           consult                 1.00    
2                   2           lab services)(comp)     1.00    
3                   3           urine analysis          1.00    
4                   3           metacam                 0.34
5                   3           mirtazapine             1.00    
6                   4           mirtazapine             1.00    
7                   4           fluid administration    1.00    
8                   5           fluid set up iv         1.00
9                   6           mirtazapine             1.00    
10                  6           hospitalisation         1.00
```

From this i want to make a temp table of invoice key and invoicedetails key so i can find the average number of invoice line items per invoice.

(invoice details are id's for specific line items and invoice key are which invoice they are from 'invoice 2, invoice 3 etc)

I started with

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
Invoicekey int,
invoicedetails_key int
)

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable

INSERT INTO #TempTable 
SELECT [invoicedetails_key], [invoicekey]  
FROM [dbo].[vetfeesinvoicedetails]

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable
```

What is the best way to group 'invoicedetails_key' by 'invoicekey' and then find the average ?

Comment: Expected results would help. Do you want the average number of rows per `invoicekey`, or the average sum of `invoicedetails_itemqty` per `invoicekey`, or something else? How does `invoicedetails_key` come into this, how would you "group 'invoicedetails_key' by 'invoicekey' and then find the average"? You can't group one colum by another, instead you group a whole resultset by one or more columns

Comment: @Charlieface i need to report the average number of invoice lines (invoicedetails_key) per invoice (invoicekey). So i would presume that i need to group invoicedetails_key (line items) by invoicekey (invoice id) and the find the average.

Comment: Like I said, `invoicedetails_key` is irrelevant here, you just want the average number of rows per `invoicekey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by `invoicekey` and get the count of rows, then aggregate again and get the average of all groups.

```sql
SELECT
  AVG(id.count * 1.0) AS AverageCount,
  AVG(id.TotalQty * 1.0) AS AverageQty
FROM (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS count,
      SUM(id.invoicedetails_itemqty) AS TotalQty
    FROM dbo.vetfeesinvoicedetails id
    GROUP BY
      id.invoicekey
) id;
```

Comment: ERROR - Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator --- any ideas @charlieface ??

Comment: I see no `varchar` columns in your definition. If `invoicedetails_itemqty` is `varchar` you should ideally change it to `int` or `decimal`, or you can cast it like this `SUM(CAST(id.invoicedetails_itemqty AS decimal(18,9)))`

Comment: Okay so i did it step by step using your idea and managed to come up with this that gave me the correct answer.                     `  SELECT [invoicedetails_key], [invoicekey]  
INTO #TempTable3 
FROM [Insights].[dbo].[vetfeesinvoicedetails]

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable3

SELECT (cast(invoicekey as int)) as 'Avg'
FROM #TempTable3
GROUP BY invoicekey

SELECT invoicekey, COUNT(invoicedetails_key) AS 'numberoflineitems'
INTO #TempTable4
FROM #TempTable3
GROUP BY invoicekey
ORDER BY invoicekey asc

SELECT AVG(cast(numberoflineitems as decimal(16,4))) as 'Avg'
FROM #TempTable4 `

Comment: Those temp tables are completely unnecessary, you can just nest the selects like this `SELECT AVG(cast(numberoflineitems as decimal(16,4))) as Avg FROM (SELECT invoicekey, COUNT(*) AS numberoflineitems FROM dbo.vetfeesinvoicedetails GROUP BY invoicekey) iv;`

Comment: Ah thats abit better looking. Many thanks much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i did it step by step using @Charlieface's idea and managed to come up with this that gave me the correct answer.

````
SELECT [invoicedetails_key], [invoicekey]  
INTO #TempTable3 
FROM [dbo].[vetfeesinvoicedetails]

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable3

SELECT (cast(invoicekey as int)) as 'Avg'
FROM #TempTable3
GROUP BY invoicekey

SELECT invoicekey, COUNT(invoicedetails_key) AS 'numberoflineitems'
INTO #TempTable4
FROM #TempTable3
GROUP BY invoicekey
ORDER BY invoicekey asc

SELECT AVG(cast(numberoflineitems as decimal(16,4))) as 'Avg'
FROM #TempTable4 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get data into temp table. You can just group by invoicekey, then use AVG() function in the select statement.

If you mean average of item qty, then it's

```
SELECT AVG([invoicedetails_itemqty])  
FROM [dbo].[vetfeesinvoicedetails]
GROUP BY [invoicekey]
```

Not quite sure what you mean by "find the average number of invoice line items per invoice". Can you show me the sample supposed result from this grid above?

Comment: Just tried SELECT [invoicedetails_key], AVG([invoicekey]) AS 'avginv'
FROM [dbo].[vetfeesinvoicedetails]
GROUP BY invoicekey and got this back -------------- Column 'dbo.vetfeesinvoicedetails.invoicedetails_key' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: In addition to describing the solution, please provide a working solution.

Comment: @crazy-coder i need to find the average number of [invoicedetails_key] from the invoices in [invoicekey]. [invoicedetails_key] are the id's of specific line items from invoices. [invoicekey] is the invoice number it relates to. So i presume i need to group the data by invoice key so for example invoice 2 has 2 line items - and then find the average ? Thats why i was trying the temp table to group it and then average it.

Comment: @L_G92 Not sure why you need average, it seems like you want the count of [invoicekey]. For example, invoicekey "2" has 2 count, and "3" has 3 count, "4" has 2 count, "5" has 1 count, "6" has 2 count. Is this the result you need?

Comment: No i need the average lines per invoice. So the actual databse im using has 285k rows of invoice items. For reporting purposes i want to report the average number of invoice lines per invoice.